# unable to create report in crystal reports 2013 with oracle stored procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a report in crystal 2013 based on an oracle stored procedure. my procedure takes an input parameter and returns a strongly bound ref cursor. This procedure works well when it is run in sql*plus. When I select the procedure in database expert, I am prompted to enter the values for the input parameter and all other columns in ref cursor. I set the parameters to default value (Set to Null box checked) and pressed OK button. The following error message is received.

> Database Connector Error: 'HY000:[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CR_TEST_PROC2'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 8:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   [Database Vendor Code: 6550]

Even if I provide the arguments I get the same error. I use OraClient 11g_home1 driver in my datasource. It seems like there is not much support for oracle stored procedures in crystal. Not sure if the issue is with driver. I wanted to see if anyone has encountered this issue and how they resolved it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you provide the call from sqlplus and crystal?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Provide a value for your parameter instead of null (any value is ok it doesn't need to be one that will return records) and try mapping it to your report.
2. If the above doesnt work, can you try using oracle service (from your description, it seems like you are using an ODBC driver to connect) to link the stored procedure to your report? For this method, you will need to use the exact service name as mentioned in your tnsnames.ora file.

Hope this helps.